# OSX Lion ctags Java support

Tags: java, xcode, osx-lion, ctags

I am running OSX Lion with Xcode 4.2.1 installed. Does the ctags that comes with Xcode support java or do I have to try an build exuberant crags?

Also, I noticed there is a ctags in /usr/bin/ctags and /Developer/usr/bin/ctags. Are they different?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all I know /usr/bin/ctags and /Developer/usr/bin/ctags are the same. I believe they are very old versions of ctags that comes shipped with OSX. You can check the version on the manpage if it has any. I suggest you install ctags from the [brew](https://brew.sh) package manager. Brew ships exuberant ctags 5.8 and I'm guessing this is the ctags that you want to use.

Trivia: I think OSX mirrors some unix files into non unix standard, osx-style directories. For instance, /usr/bin/ctags and /Developer/usr/bin/ctags are the same. The same is also true for /etc/hosts and /private/etc/hosts. However ls -l shows that the mirrored files are not softlinks. I'm guessing that they are hardlinks, but I'm not sure about this because I'm a relatively new OSX user.